# How to disappear/disable background scrollbar?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Modal container which pops up on screen and has its own scrollbar. However I can still scroll the background contents behind the modal. This is distractive and most irritating. Is there a way to disable the background scrollbar when the popup modal is open? Using blazor.

I'm only using css, html and c#. No Js or anything else.
Note: the scrollbars should be there when the browser becomes smaller by default the popup usually fits on screen.

```
    .backgroundPopupBox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.addUserPopupBox {
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 28px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}



/* Browsers Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px; /*for vertical scrollbar */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #777;
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

HTML PAGE

```
    @page "/test"


<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addButton" @onclick="@(e => newUserComponent.Open())">Add <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>


<NewProduct @ref="newProductComponent"></NewProduct>

@code {
    private NewProduct? newProductComponent { get; set; }


}
```

MODAL

```
<div class="modal @ModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@ModalDisplay">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="backgroundPopupBox">
                <div class="addUserPopupBox">
                    <h2>No overscroll chaining</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat leo eu odio feugiat luctus. Duis vel sagittis ipsum, non dictum nisl. Vivamus sit amet volutpat metus. Nunc tempus, mi ut vehicula porttitor, velit lacus sagittis lorem, sit amet venenatis mauris nibh sit amet urna. Nam nibh mi, commodo id diam eu, congue suscipit nunc. Vestibulum scelerisque dui tempus tincidunt luctus. Donec placerat quis neque vel ultrices. Pellentesque dignissim placerat orci sed cursus. Ut convallis leo sapien, vitae ornare nulla sodales at. Suspendisse ut vestibulum erat. Sed ut fermentum tortor. Integer quis tellus eget nisi pharetra pharetra non vitae magna. Cras ultricies, nulla id imperdiet varius, nisi odio finibus diam, at finibus lacus risus vel dui. Ut euismod consequat libero eu pharetra.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-secondary button" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="Close">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private string ModalDisplay = "none;";
    private string ModalClass = "";

    public void Open()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "Show";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "none";
        ModalClass = "";
        StateHasChanged();
    } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Just a suggestion, why can't you use close button for Modal and disable everything behind the Modal

Comment: @Bhuvaneshwaran I wasn't aware that I could disable anything? Right now everything is in divs. Could you clarify? The modal does contain a close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temporary CSS once the modal opens to force the scrollbar to no longer be rendered and then remove that CSS when closed:

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}
```